# Openstack instance status is "error"

Tags: openstack

I create a instance in horizon. But its status is "error". Then I run

```
virsh list --all
```

There is nothing. I have checked log files, including nova/api.log, nova/compute.log, and I can not find any clues. Could someone give some advice ?

Comment: how about horizon log? can you boot a VM over nova client?

Comment: check the scheduler log, and nova-compute logs on the host it was deployed to.

Comment: also the nova client has a --debug flag that can be obscenely verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using devstack? In that case you should make

```
cd ~/devstack
./rejoinstack.sh
```

After that you will be executing "screen" tool, with pressing Ctrl+a and then " you will see all the services running and their logs, so when you have it you have to reproduce the error again and see in the different services until you see where the error is happening.

To exit from screen you have to press Ctrl+a and then d